# localstorage of a classlist

Tags: javascript, class, local-storage

soo, i am trying to use localstorage to store the classlist so it will remember whether or not something was added to their favorites list. i need to do this with JavaScript. The error provided comes from the console in my web browser (chrome)

The ERROR

```
main.js:99 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at storeFavo (main.js:99)
    at HTMLButtonElement.favorites (main.js:71)
```

HTML

```
<!--  Showcase  -->
<section class="showcase">
    <div class="container grid ">

        <div class="showcase-form card">
            <h2>*Input Car Name*</h2>
            <img alt="" src="#" >
            <button id="favo" class="btn">Add to Favorites</button>
            <button id="info" class="btn">More Info</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);

const info = document.querySelector('#info');
const div1 = document.querySelector('.moreInfo');
const favo = document.querySelector('#favo');
let apiUrl = 'webservice/includes/actions.php';
let apiUrl2 = 'webservice/index.php';
let Favos = document.getElementById('favo').getElementsByClassName('favorited')[0];

function init() {
    info.addEventListener('click', moreInfo);
    favo.addEventListener('click', favorites);

    if (typeof window.localStorage === "undefined") {
        console.error('Local storage is not available in your browser');
        return;
    }
    checkFromLocalStorage()
    carList;
}
function carList() {
    fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(getAjaxSuccessHandler)
        .catch(getAjaxErrorHandler);
}
function getAjaxSuccessHandler(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
function getAjaxErrorHandler(data) {
    console.error(data);
}

// Generate Cards

// getCars.map((item)=>{
//     return (
//         <div>
//             <p> {item.brand}</p>
//             <p> {item.type}</p>
//         </div>
//     );
// }),

// More Info Button
    function moreInfo() {
        let title= document.createElement('h1');
        title.innerHTML = 'Info';
        div1.appendChild(title)
        console.log("info?")
        if (div1.style.display == 'block'){
            div1.style.display = 'none';
        } else  {
            div1.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

// Add To Favorites Button

function favorites() {
    console.log("favo")
    if (favo.classList == 'btn') {
        favo.classList.remove('btn')
        favo.classList.add('favorited')
        favo.innerHTML = 'Remove from favorites';
        storeFavo()
    }
    else {
        favo.classList.remove('favorited')
        favo.classList.add('btn')
        favo.innerHTML = 'Add to Favorites';
        deleteClickHandler()
    }
}

//Check
/**
 * Is local storage is available on page load? Let's fill the form
 */
function checkFromLocalStorage() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('favos') !== null) {
        Favos.value = localStorage.getItem('favos');
    }
}

//Store
/**
 * After submitting the form, let's save the values in the local storage
 *
 * @param e
 */

function storeFavo(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('favos', Favos.value);
    localStorage['Favos'] = document.getElementById("favo")
}

//Delete
/**
 * Make sure we clean up the local storage again
 *
 * @param e
 */
function deleteClickHandler(e) {
    localStorage.removeItem('favos');
}
```

CSS

```
.favorited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #470aed;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I will do my very best to respond fast and to provide any needed information if asked for.

Comment: use data-* attributes then put the value into an array and then stringify it into localstorage, then on init, get json from localstorage, then parse and loop over array then you can easily match the element to set the state

Comment: You should initialize `Favos` in the `init()`, after the document is ready. So leave a `let Favos;` on the top level, but move the `Favos = ...` part in the load-handler. However as there is no reason for any of the elements(?) being favorited after loading the document, so the `[0]` of an empty array still will likely be `undefined`. And while what the `getElementsBy...` functions return are live collections, taking a given element of such collection is not live any more, that `undefined` value will stay `undefined` even if the user marks something as favorite afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation of localStorage.setItem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem, you can write only string values, but you are trying to write an Object value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). If you want to have some persistence fo your HTML element, you can save outerHTML https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML to the storage and parse it on load.